# How to read the web.config values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've a client side project with Html screen like below.

[image]

I Need to read the BaseUrl value from web.config file

I Tried With the below code.

```
var varName = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"]';
  
   var appStr = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"].ToString() %>'
```

But it's not reading the values . Let me know if you've any better idea to read the values.
[image]

Comment: Are you using some backend, like asp.net?, If so you might want to add the tag.

Comment: we have .net api separately